# Drawing natural numbers without replacement.

Tags: pr.probability, probabilistic-number-theory, stochastic-processes, nt.number-theory, st.statistics

Suppose we start with an initial probability distribution on $\mathbb{N}$ that gives positive probability to each $n$. Let's call this random variable $X_1$ so we have $P(X_1=n)=p_{1,n}>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. $X_1$ wil be the first draw from $\mathbb{N}$. For the next draw $X_2$ we define a new distribution on $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{ X_1 \}$ by rescaling the remaining probabilities so they add up to 1. So $p_{2,X_1}=0$ and $p_{2,n}=\frac{p_{1,n}}{1-p_{1,X_1}}$ for $n\neq X_1$. Continuing in this manner we get a stochastic process (certainly not Markov) that corresponds to drawing from $\mathbb{N}$ without replacement. My question is whether this process has ever been studied in the literature. In particular, I'm wondering if a clever choice of the initial distribution could result in tractable expressions for the distributions of $X_n$ for large $n$.

Comment: I have not read Feller's classic text on probability.  The reputation of the text, however, I have heard.  Thus I wager a small amount of money that this subject is discussed, perhaps in a different form, in that text.  Gerhard "Say A Nickel, Any Takers?" Paseman, 2011.08.26 

Comment: Don't know if this has been studied, but $p_{1,n} \propto e^{-cn}$ would certainly lead to nice results.  This initial distribution has a certain renewal property: after the first step $N_1$ at which we have drawn exactly the first $n$ integers for some $n$ the process looks the same as the initial process but shifted by $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ and shifted by $N_1$ in time. Not sure if that is clear... 

Comment: @Jeff, hmmm... at time $N_1$, with positive probability some integers greater than $n$ have already been drawn and then the set of the values still available is not a shift of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @Didier:  I think Jeff means shifted by $N_1-n$ in time.  This seems to me to be correct.

Comment: @Daniel, I do not understand. Let me put it another way: at least for some distributions (p_n), with positive probability there exists no time T (except time 1) such that at time T the set of the integers already drawn is a segment.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the number of renewals is almost surely finite.

Comment: Do you want the (unconditional) distribution of $X_n$?  That is the same as the distribution of $X_1$.

Comment: This is an interesting question even though, as Robert Israel points out, the question explicitly posed is trivially solved and uninteresting.

Comment: @Robert, X_1 and X_2 are never equidistributed.

Comment: @Michael, see comment above.

Comment: @Didier:  Jeff is talking about a particular small class of distributions, with $p_{1,n}=Ce^{-cn}$.

Comment: @Daniel: OK. And?

Comment: This model of drawing without replacement is used by professional poker players to estimate the probability of finishing in $n$th place in a tournament given a particular distribution of chips. It is called the Independent Chip Model or ICM. I proved that in heads-up pots in tournaments with nondecreasing prizes, the ICM always recommends a nonnegative amount of risk-aversion. For example, according to the ICM it is not worth it to spend some chips on average to try to knock someone out.

Comment: @Didier: $\Pr(X_2 = x) = \Pr(X_1 \neq x\text{ and }X_2 = x)$ $= \Pr(X_1 \neq x)\cdot \Pr(X_2 = x \mid X_1 \neq x)$ $= (1-p_x)\left( \frac{p_x}{1-p_x} \right) = p_x = \Pr(X_1 = x)$.  So you're mistaken: they are equidistributed.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: If $Pr(X_1=1)=0.9$, then $Pr(X_2=1)$ can't be $0.9$ since  the events are disjoint. 

Comment: For $Pr(X_1 = n) = 1/2^n$, Mathematica says $Pr(X_2 = 1) = 3/4 - \text{QPolyGamma}[0,2,2]/ \text{Log}[4] = 0.303348$. 

Comment: For any $n$, there is almost surely some index $f(n)$ so that $X_{f(n)}=n$. $Pr(f(n) \lt f(m)) = p_{1,n}/(p_{1,n}+p_{1.m})$. In the poker version, the odds that player $n$ outlasts player $m$ is the ratio between their stacks. 

Comment: I see: $\Pr(X_2 = 1 \mid X_1 \neq 1) = \frac{p_1}{1-p_1}$ only if $p_2=p_3=p_4=\cdots$.  The familiar argument showing the marginals are all the same works only for uniform distributions.  $\Pr(X_2=1) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{p_1}{1-p_i}\cdot p_i$.  If all $p_i$ are equal, then this is $\left(\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}\right)p_2 + \left(\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}\right)p_3 + \left(\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}\right)p_4 + \cdots$ $=\left(\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}\right)(p_2+p_3+p_4+\cdots) = \left(\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}\right)(1-p_1)$.

Comment: @Didier:  Ah sorry, I misunderstood your confusion.  That's true of course, but Jeff's observation applies as long as a segment $[1, n]$ is contained in those integers already drawn at time $N_1$.  This happens for arbitrarily large $n$ with probability $1$.  I guess the confusion is that you want $n$ to equal $N_1$, which will of course almost never happen?

Comment: @Daniel, what you (wrongly) call my confusion (twice) is what is written in the comment above. The fact that each segment [1,n] is entirely drawn after a finite random time T_n is true but (as far as I can see) does not imply some renewal structure since (as I already said) at time T_n many integers k>n are already drawn as well and the structure of the (random) set of these k is mysterious. That is, it is mysterious to me. Please enlighten me if I missed something. (By the way, I wonder what happened to the so-called *particular small class of distributions* you mentioned earlier.)

Comment: @Douglas, did you write something about the poker applications of the model (which you seem to know well)? I would be interested. // It is an odd fact that $P(f(n)<f(m))$ is easily computed for every $n$ and $m$ although (unless I miss something) the distribution of $f(1)$ alone (for example) is mysterious.

Comment: @Didier: I didn't mean to offend--I only meant confusion as in "miscommunication," which is of course my fault, not yours. Formally, what I mean is this. `$P(X_{N}=k| [1,n]\text{ has already been drawn by time} N) =P(X_{N-n}=k-n)$` for the particular class of distributions in question. Hopefully I haven't made any indexing mistakes.

Comment: @Douglas: Do you include the ICM proof in your hold'em book?

Comment: @Binary Finary: I definitely didn't include the proof since that book is aimed at poker players not mathematicians. I think I refered to the poker consequences. I posted the proof in the twoplustwo.com forums. 

Comment: @Didier: Many poker utilities have the Independent Chip Model built in to perform calculations. At http://www.holdemresources.net you can find a Nash-equilibrium push/fold calculator which assumes the payoffs follow the ICM. You can download my program ICM Explorer from http://www.icmexplorer.com. It calculates the distribution of $f(1)$ for up to $10$ nonzero stacks as well as a few useful quantities for tournament play. I've made a few instructional videos on the ICM and implications for poker strategy, and a section of my book *The Math of Hold'em* is on it. 

Comment: @Didier: I'm not sure why you find the fact that $P(f(n)<f(m))$ easily computable odd, it is just a special case of the following easy observation: for any set of integers $S$, the relative order of $f(k)$ for $k\in S$ is distributed using the same model of drawing without replacement with the normalized distribution on $S$. This, in turn, follows from the even simpler observation that one can generate a drawing without replacement sequence by first generating a drawing with replacement sequence, then keeping just the first appearance of each element. I hope this all makes sense.

Comment: Right: one can make Ori's observation even more explicit. Let $Y_i$ be independent exponential random variables with rates $p_i$. Now consider the reordering of the values $Y_i$ into increasing order: then $X_1$ is the index of the smallest value $Y_i$, $X_2$ is the index of the second smallest value $Y_i$, etc. In particular, $P(f(n)<f(m))=P(Y_n<Y_m)=p_n/(p_n+p_m)$.  

Answer (score 4):

Here are some preliminary computations. Assume the reference distribution is $(p(n))$. For every finite subset $I$ of $\mathbb N$, introduce the finite number $r(I)\ge1$ such that
$$
\frac1{r(I)}=1-\sum_{k\in I}p(k).
$$
Obviously, $P(X_1=n)=p(n)$ for every $n$. Likewise,
$P(X_2=n)=E(p(n)r(X_1);X_1\ne n)$ hence
$$
P(X_2=n)=p(n)(\alpha-p(n)r(n)),\qquad
\alpha=\sum\limits_kp(k)r(k).
$$
This shows that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not equidistributed (if they were, $\alpha-p(n)r(n)$ would not depend on $n$, hence $p(n)$ would not either, but this is impossible since $(p(n))$ is a measure with finite mass on an infinite set).

One can also compute the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$ as
$$
P(X_1=n,X_2=k)=p(n)r(n)p(k)[k\ne n],
$$
and this allows to expand 
$$
P(X_3=n)=E(p(n)r(X_1,X_2);X_1\ne n,X_2\ne n),
$$
as the double sum
$$
P(X_3=n)=p(n)\sum_{k\ne n}\sum_{i\ne n}[k\ne i]r(k,i)p(k)r(k)p(i),
$$
but no simpler or really illuminating expression seems to emerge.

Answer (score -6):

Googling "sampling without replacement" produces more information than I could ever hope to summarize here (note that in sampling theory, the population is usually assumed to be so large as to be infinite, and the distribution is whatever you feel like, certainly not usually uniform).

Comment: Saying the population is infinite is often little more than a roundabout way of saying that the sampling is being done _with_ replacement, i.e., i.i.d.  As the population size grows, "without replacement" approaches "with replacement".

Comment: for a finite population, the multivariate hypergeometric distribution is the general answer.


http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Comment: @Carlo, for a finite population, the experiment collapses after a finite time and the distribution of X_n for large n (the object the OP is interested in) does not exist.

Comment: @Didier --- you're absolutely right; I was thinking of a double limit in which both the system size and "time" n are sent to infnity.